# Protobuf-Net error message: No Serializer defined for type: System.Type

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, system.type

I am getting the following error message when trying to serialize `List<Tuple<string, Type, object>>`: No Serializer defined for type: System.Type

I tried both, just serializing the above collection or serializing a class that has the same collection defined as protoMember. Both result in the same error message.

Is this a non-supported type? I assume it is supported and I overlooked something else but maybe I am incorrect?

Thanks for any pointers that may help resolve this...

Comment: See updated answer; this is actually included in later builds

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit:

Support for `Type` serialization is included in r580

---

protobuf-net is intended to serialize your *data*, not your implementation; `Type` is an implementation detail. Strictly speaking, it wouldn't be hugely hard to add (some of the implementation-specific details already essentially end up storing `Type` info, via the assembly-qualified-name), but: it isn't a key scenario, and in many ways is *not* something I would encourage you to serialize - the whole point of protocol buffers is that you can load the data on any platform, with version tolerance a key feature. Storing `Type` information violates both of these.

It should also be noted that most *other* serializers (except perhaps `BinaryFormatter`, which already breaks every rule of platform/version-tolerance) will ***also*** refuse to serialize a `Type`; `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer` etc ***all*** throw an exception for this scenario (I just checked them).

Additionally: `object` is *even less* supportable, unless you use the `DynamicType` feature.

---

Here's how it could be done via a surrogate on `Type`:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // register a surrogate for Type
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Type), false)
                                .SetSurrogate(typeof(TypeSurrogate));
        // test it
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(new Foo { Type = typeof(string) });
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
class TypeSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string AssemblyQualifiedName { get; set; }
    // protobuf-net wants an implicit or explicit operator between the types
    public static implicit operator Type(TypeSurrogate value)
    {
        return value==null ? null : Type.GetType(value.AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }
    public static implicit operator TypeSurrogate(Type value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : new TypeSurrogate {
            AssemblyQualifiedName  = value.AssemblyQualifiedName };
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. But how would you go about serializing such collection? I need to send it over a message bus that only allows byte arrays to be transported. Is transforming Type to a string and then converting it back to a Type an option? I concur with you re object types, I think I asked you before and you pointed me to the DynamicType feature.

Comment: @Freddy indeed, the simplest thing would be to store `string, string, object`, using the `.AssemblyQualifiedName` and `Type.GetType(string)`. If you wanted to get *really* exotic, you could probably add a *surrogate* for `Type` (protobuf-net supports that). At the technical level, I *could* support it directly without too much pain, but it just seems like I'd be making it far to easy for people to shoot themselves in the foot... with a bazooka.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, really appreciate. It sounds reasonable to keep the library as is given that platform and version independence is the desired target. I already assumed what you described in your answer in that you store types through assembly qualified names, otherwise I probably do not understand how the deserializer later handles its tasks without the help of type information. But I may be completely off as I have not looked at your source code at all.

Comment: last question: I would like to embed the conversion from Type to string and later string back to Type within the class that contains the protoMember collection `List<Tuple<string, string, dynamic>>`. At serialization time that is easy as I can do the conversion within the constructor. However, is there a way to do the conversion back to Type implicitly at deserialization time? Is there a way to specify a method that is called AFTER deserialization of the collection but BEFORE returning the deserialized class object so that manipulations can be performed?

Comment: @Freddy in **most** cases, when you deserialize you *tell* it what type you want, or for sub-objects, it knows the type via property information etc. It is only in DynamicType that it doesn't know in advance, and for that it uses AssemblyQualifiedName etc as above (by default, at least). For your *last* question, that is where a *surrogate* comes in - but this gets a *little* tricky because `Tuple<...>` already has a particular flavor of handling. Adding a *surrogate* for `Type` is probably easier... 2 seconds...

Comment: @Freddy example of surrogate approach added to answer; important step is the `SetSurrogate`.

Comment: I may get rusty but could you please quickly point out how to serialize `List<Tuple<string, string, object>>` using protobuf-net, please? I specify the above object within a ProtoContract class through [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)] but it still throws an error saying that the object cannot be serialized.

Comment: Marc, I also get issues when trying to serialize/deserialize `List<object>` though I have [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)] set which is strange. It serializes ok but when trying to deserialize it throws the error message "Internal Error: a missing key occurred". Any idea what I am messing up here?

Comment: For the second: I would need to look; for the first, hmmm, there's no easy way to do that currently - alas, I don't claim protobuf-net can handle every obscure setup. Can you generate a DTO class instead of using Tuple?

Comment: I got around it by using the .net serializer because it was about a non speed critical component. For everything else I do use protobuf.net. Thanks for your elaborate help. I would up vote multiple times if I could. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Marc, does `Type` serialization still work in r666? It return `null` after deserialization.

Comment: @TeddyBo not in my tests, it doesn't... do you have a failing test I can look at? Here's mine: http://pastie.org/8335904

Comment: I've found the problem. The property `AssemblyQualifiedName` is used to serialize `Type`. Unfortunately in my case there are files that are shared between different projects using `Add as Link`. It leads to different values stored in that property.

Comment: As I understand I can handle this using `DynamicTypeFormatting`.

Comment: @Teddy yes - you can use this event to control this