# Protobuf-net: Changing the way System.Type is deserialized

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Currently we have several messages defined that include System.Type fields/properties. The built-in behavior how protobuf-net deals with System.Type is fine in many cases, but unusable in our situation: We do want to have the type serialize its full name, but need to be in control of the lookup by name.

I am unable to find a proper and working solution for this. On the one hand, there is the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475521/protobuf-net-error-message-no-serializer-defined-for-type-system-type) that explains how to register a surrogate for System.Type, but unfortunately that seems to be no longer working, as a System.Argument exception is thrown with "Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model in this way: System.Type".

On the other hand there is the "TypeModel.DynamicTypeFormatting" event which doesn't seem to be invoked in a case like the following:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo { [ProtoMember] public List<Type> Types; }
```

Is there currently a way to solve this problem quickly without shipping a custom version with a quickfix on our side?

Comment: Suggestion: why would you not simply serialize a `List<string>` or similar?

Comment: While possible i would prefer a solution that doesn't require every message to go through an additional step in order to obtain the list of types again. Is there a specific reason the solution with surrogates doesnt work?

Comment: Another reason why I hesitate to change the message format is that we already have tons of data containing serialized messages like above and I would hate to have to produce it again.

Comment: k; I need to take a look at what is happening in this scenario

Comment: I dug a little deeper into the sources and found out why DynamicTypeFormatting didn't work for me: We use a compiled TypeModel and I registered the event on the original model, not the one returned via TypeModel.Compile(). Registering an event handler on the correct instance now works as expected - Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Ah, right; that would explain it, then; you might want to add your edit as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I registered the DynamicTypeFormatting event on the wrong TypeModel instance:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model.DynamicTypeFormatting += Callback;
var compiledModel = model.Compile();
compiledModel.Deserialize();this is a completely different instance
```

won't work, because I would need to register the callback on 'compiledModel' instead. Fixing this minor mistake finally allowed me to customize the way that Type lookups are performed upon deserialization.